# Threading is slow and unpredictable?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I've created the basis of a ray tracer, here's my testing function for drawing the scene:

```
public void Trace(int start, int jump, Sphere testSphere)
{
    for (int x = start; x < scene.SceneWidth; x += jump)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < scene.SceneHeight; y++)
        {
            Ray fired = Ray.FireThroughPixel(scene, x, y);

            if (testSphere.Intersects(fired))
                sceneRenderer.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Red);
            else sceneRenderer.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Black);
        }
    }
}
```

SetPixel simply sets a value in a single dimensional array of colours.  If I call the function normally by just directly calling it it runs at a constant 55fps.  If I do:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(() => Trace(0, 1, testSphere));
t1.Start();
t1.Join();
```

It runs at a constant 50fps which is fine and understandable, but when I do:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(() => Trace(0, 2, testSphere));
Thread t2 = new Thread(() => Trace(1, 2, testSphere));

t1.Start();
t2.Start();

t1.Join();
t2.Join();
```

It runs all over the place, rapidly moving between 30-40 fps and sometimes going out of that range up to 50 or down to 20, it's not constant at all.  Why is it running slower than it would if I ran the whole thing on a single thread?  I'm running on a quad core i5 2500k.

Comment: Maybe it's just me.. but the `Join` calls seem suspicious. Where is your FPS calculated? In the thread creating these new threads or in another separate thread?

Comment: Multi-threaded apps can only speed things up when there is no dependency between threads, when a multi-core processor is available and when the compiler and the OS take advantage of your hardware resources. In your case I would guess that your threads are concurring to access the global [Bitmap object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4e7y164x.aspx#ThreadSafety) (*sceneRenderer*), which prevents two threads from using it at the same time.

Comment: I'm with @SimonWhitehead, assuming the threads don't start on create, the behaviour of the threads can't be predicted, if t2 blocks t1, you'll be all over the place

Comment: One question - you posted some code, but as i understand, you are calling those methods (i.e. creating threads) in some kind of a loop? If yes - you should know, that creating new threads, is incredibly inefficient, and you should avoid it. Maybe you can try using `ThreadPool` class or `Task<T>` classes instead?

Comment: I don't believe that's the problem as creating both threads but then doing t1.Start(); t1.Join(); t2.Start(); t2.Join(); goes back to just below the 50fps mark.

Comment: Thanks, ThreadPool has solved it :), it's now running at 190fps.

Answer (score 3):

This is difficult to answer without profiling your app, but I would suspect false sharing.

Both your threads are writing to a shared memory structure, which will cause your CPU caches to keep invalidating.

The easy way to test would be to create a separate output array for each thread.

It doesn't have to work - just look at the frame rates.

I wrote an article about this a while back: "[Concurrency Hazards: False Sharing](http://simplygenius.net/Article/FalseSharing)"

Comment: Commenting out the setpixel function had the same effect, same speed differences.  So I cloned the scene and added the scene as a parameter on Trace, now I get extreme slow downs (60% slower) when I do: Trace(0, 2, testSphere, scene);Trace(1, 2, testSphere2, scene); As opposed to Trace(0, 1, testSphere, scene);, same with threading it.

Answer (score 0):

Threading usually isn't the way to go with rendering. I don't know what exactly is executed within the thread, but it's possible that creating the threads and joining them costs more time than what you win by the parallel calculation. Depends on the amount of processor cores too.

Comment: I disagree with "Threading isn't the way to go with rendering". There are many examples of it being done correctly and achieving performance benefits. Also, "Depends on the amount of processor cores" is irrelevant, because Jake said he is running a quad core.

Comment: true, but it's counterproductive in small renders.

Comment: Raytracing is embarassingly parallel, in theory.

Answer (score 0):

Experiment: Exchange x with y, go through x in the inner loop and y in the outer loop, and always distribute the load per thread line-wise, never column-wise (x).

My assumption is based on the fact that bitmaps are almost always stored with ascending memory addresses in the x-direction . If that is the case, your current memory access pattern is hard on the CPU caches, especially when multiple threads are used.